Halbach array of magnets
I have been reading into Halbach arrays of magnets as a part of doing a hardware project. My question is: Is it possible to create a circular ring of Halbach array of magnets such that at the center of circle, the magnetic field is maximum and the remaining points both inside as well as outside the circle, the magnetic field is zero or almost negligible? If it is possible, what should be the minimum number of magnets required to achieve this?

Similar questions have been raised and discussed, e.g. here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162620/can-a-magnetic-field-be-focused-at-a-distance
The answer is no. The field in some point away from the magnets will not be stronger than anywhere else. If you go closer to the ring in your case you will always find points where it is stronger than in the center.

I'm having a hard time imagining the geometry you want and the field direction.  My quick response is that you could probably better achieve what you want with a solenoid and iron or mu-metal concentrators.
