# Concentration and manipulation of magnetic fields

Tags: electromagnetism, propulsion

is it possible to concentrate magnetic fields, via concave electric coils? If a current is induced in such as a concave cylinder shaped coil.

Comment: I think what you are looking for can more likely be found under "magnetic implosion experiments".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can magnetic fields be redirected and focused at one point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17200/)

Comment: [Searching this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=focus+magnetic) will find several other related questions.