# Create a magnetic field whose energy is mostly outside of the assembly creating it

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm aware of a number of schemes to concentrate a magnetic field inside an area. Most obviously, the total field strength inside a solenoid is much greater than the total field strength outside of it. Is the reverse possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can magnetic fields be redirected and focused at one point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17200/can-magnetic-fields-be-redirected-and-focused-at-one-point)

Comment: Yes, I saw that question, and someone in one of the *answers* asks this question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a hollow cylinder with current running along it. The inside has no magnetic field but the outside has magnetic field.

Comment: Huh. It looks like (for an infinitely long cylinder anyway) half the energy goes into shell and half to the space outside.